# Can't create VM in Seoul Region

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I cannot create a VM in the Seoul Region (northeast3) on GCP.

I can easily create VM in other regions.

Seoul region was [launched on January 24 2020](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/release-notes?hl=en_US).

I get the following error in the notifications:

> The request contains invalid arguments: "Invalid value for field 'zone': 'asia-northeast3-a'. Unknown zone.". Error code: "invalid"

I use the web form to create the most basic VM (all default settings). I tried on different projects, same result. I tried other zone (a,b,c) with the same result.

When running through Gcloud instead of the Web UI:

> gcloud beta compute --project=xxxxxxxxx instances create instance-3 --zone=asia-northeast3-a --machine-type=n1-standard-2 --verbosity=debug
>   DEBUG: Running [gcloud.beta.compute.instances.create] with arguments: [--machine-type: "n1-standard-2", --project: "xxxxxxxxxxxx", --verbosity: "debug", --zone: "asia-northeast3-a", INSTANCE_NAMES:1: "[u'instance-3']"]
>   DEBUG: (gcloud.beta.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
>    - Invalid value for field 'zone': 'asia-northeast3-a'. Unknown zone.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 981, in Execute
>       resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
>     File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 807, in Run
>       resources = command_instance.Run(args)
>     File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/compute/instances/create.py", line 554, in Run
>       return compute_client.MakeRequests(requests)
>     File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/compute/client_adapter.py", line 97, in MakeRequests
>       errors, error_message='Could not fetch resource:')
>     File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/compute/utils.py", line 119, in RaiseToolException
>       RaiseException(problems, calliope_exceptions.ToolException, error_message)
>     File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/compute/utils.py", line 131, in RaiseException
>       errors))
>   ToolException: Could not fetch resource:
>    - Invalid value for field 'zone': 'asia-northeast3-a'. Unknown zone.
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
>    - Invalid value for field 'zone': 'asia-northeast3-a'. Unknown zone.

Comment: Is this issue still happening? I was able to create a VM Instance (GCE). If you try to run this command: `gcloud beta compute --project=xxxxxx instances create instance-3 --zone=asia-northeast3-a --machine-type=n1-standard-2 --verbosity=debug` what error did you get? Remember to obfuscate your personal information like your Project ID and username.

Comment: Hi Armando, I've added the debug logs in my original question (too long for comment reply). Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Hey Merton. I have also tried deploying a VM on asia-northeast3-a and was able to create the Compute Engine Instance successfully. I have one question for you. What is your current gcloud version? This could help us troubleshooting the issue. The gcloud version of my Cloud shell is 280.0.0. You could try updating it and running the command again.

Comment: Hi Oqueli, I also use the version 280.0.0 (I use the gcloud on the platform directly, using the browser).

Comment: Have you tried it with another project? I would recommend you to create a new project and try to create an instance in that zone. This could narrow the issue down.

Comment: Yes I tried that. I'm trying to resolve the issue with GCP support.